# Voltage regulator using bipolar NPN transistor

Tags: rectifier, zener, npn, schottky

I came across a circuit, and I got some questions about it.[image]

1. What is the reasoning behind using the NPN-transistor?
2. What part of the circuit draws the most current?

Comment: Did you happen to "come across" the circuit in your textbook, together with the questions? :P

Comment: I did find the circuit related to schoolwork, but the questions are purely for my own understanding.

Comment: It seams a little odd that the designer has used a 3.3V zener (i.e. one whose voltage drop is equal to a value that is commonly used as a circuit supply voltage) when there is a ~0.6V drop between the reference it produces and the load.  A 3.9V zener would seem to be much more useful in a circuit like this, making Vo approximately 3.3v, rather than the 2.7v or so you'd expect from the circuit as it stands.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the reasoning behind using the NPN-transistor?

The NPN is configured as an emitter follower and basically this means if you set a certain voltage on the base (using the low power zener), the voltage on the emitter will be between 0.5V and 1V lower on the emitter across a large range of load resistances.

In other words it's a unity gain voltage amplifier - whatever current is demanded by the load (within reason), the output voltage will be largely maintained at a fairly constant value. It's not as good as (say) an integrated linear regulator like the LM78xx series but it has its uses.

> What part of the circuit draws the most current?

With no load connected the zener draws the most current. With a full load on the output, the NPN takes the most current in order to feed *that* current to the load.

Comment: During power-up, the part that draws the most current is the capacitor, and hence, also the diode. And with a load connected, the load current passes through both the NPN and the diode.

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami thank you for your transient analysis. It supplements my steady state analysis very nicely.

Comment: To be more specific than @ClaudioAviChami, the diode is the component which draws the most current.

Comment: And of course the negative terminal of the power supply!